# How long can one drive using an Indian Driving License in California?

Tags: usa, legal, driving-licenses, california, indian-citizens

How long can one drive using an Indian Driving License (in English) in California? I have tried to research this one, but there's conflicting information on the Internet. Some say 1 month, some say 3 and while there are few accounts of 1 year too. I tried looking up the DMV website, but couldn't find any info.

Comment: If you mean you moved to California.  This would really be a question for the expats site. But note that: Cali has on the order of *five million* illegal immigrants. (Almost all of whom simply drive with no license at all.)  It is inconceivable you'd get in to any issues, at all, for using your foreign license for too long - you know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on if you are a visitor or if you are a Californian resident. Visitors are allowed to use their foreign driver's licence without limitation. If you become a resident of California, you must obtain a Californa driver's license within 10 days.

Source: [California DMV](http://www.dmv.ca.gov/dl/dl_info.htm#two500)

Comment: Again, the number of new residents over-doing that "10 day limit" would be literally some millions of people!