# Can I drive in California on a valid Indian driving licence?

Tags: indian-citizens, car-rentals, driving-licenses, california

Can I drive in California on a valid Indian driving licence? The drivers license is in English and I will be on a temporary visitors visa for about 15 days. I would like to rent a car to drive around. Would I require any more documents in order to rent a car?

Comment: Also see *[How long can one drive using an Indian Driving License in California?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7121)*

Answer (score 6):

California does not recognize IDPs. [This Calif DMV page](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/dl/dl_info#international) says:

> The State of California does not recognize an International Driving Permit (IDP) as a valid driver license (DL). California does recognize a valid driver license that is issued by a foreign jurisdiction (country, state, territory) of which the license holder is a resident.
>
> The IDP is only a translation of information contained on a person's foreign driver license and is not required to operate a motor vehicle in California. Citations issued to a person in California who has an IDP, but does not have a California driver license will be placed on the Department of Motor Vehicle database.

Thus, presuming you have a valid driving license from your country of residence, you do not need to obtain an IDP for driving in California as a tourist.

Answer (score -4):

You should get an international drivers permit. Basically it's a document that's internationally recognized. I don't know for India, but in Denmark it's issued by the same authorities who issues regular drivers' license. It takes 10-15 minutes to make and cost me around 4-5USD to get.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit

Comment: iDPs are *not* required in the US (except, weirdly, in Georgia).  If your Indian license is in English, that's good enough.